# Setting JSON object name in WCF REST

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest

I am sending JSON:

```
[
{
    "Description": "A kud ces bolje",
    "ItemID": 1,
    "Name": "Banane",
    "NewPrice": 91.99,
    "OldPrice": 161.99,
    "SaleEnds": "9/1/2013",
    "SaleStarts": "9/1/2012"
},
{
    "Description": "Rastu na stablu",
    "ItemID": 2,
    "Name": "Kruske",
    "NewPrice": 93.99,
    "OldPrice": 117.99,
    "SaleEnds": "9/1/2013",
    "SaleStarts": "9/1/2012"
},
]
```

But I want to have a name so that it looks like

```
"Some_Name":[
{
    "Description": "A kud ces bolje",
    "ItemID": 1,
    "Name": "Banane",
    "NewPrice": 91.99,
    "OldPrice": 161.99,
    "SaleEnds": "9/1/2013",
    "SaleStarts": "9/1/2012"
},
{
    "Description": "Rastu na stablu",
    "ItemID": 2,
    "Name": "Kruske",
    "NewPrice": 93.99,
    "OldPrice": 117.99,
    "SaleEnds": "9/1/2013",
    "SaleStarts": "9/1/2012"
},
]
```

I return `List<Item>`:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/items/{id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<ItemService> GetItems(string id);
```

and the `Item` is:

```
[DataContract]
public class ItemService
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Decimal OldPrice { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Decimal NewPrice { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string SaleStarts { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string SaleEnds { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't name the JSon data itself. You would need a small wrapper class containing the name:

```
class Wrapper { public Some_Name List<ItemService> {get;set;}
```

Wrap your list in the wrapper and return the wrapper.

The resulting JSon would be somehting like:

```
{
"Some_Name":[
{
    "Description": "A kud ces bolje",
    "ItemID": 1,
    "Name": "Banane",
    "NewPrice": 91.99,
    "OldPrice": 161.99,
    "SaleEnds": "9/1/2013",
    "SaleStarts": "9/1/2012"
},
{
    "Description": "Rastu na stablu",
    "ItemID": 2,
    "Name": "Kruske",
    "NewPrice": 93.99,
    "OldPrice": 117.99,
    "SaleEnds": "9/1/2013",
    "SaleStarts": "9/1/2012"
},
]}
```